# Apache or PHP replace hostname

Tags: php, linux, apache, routes, lan

Rerouting my PHP queries (CURL, fsockopen, file_get_contents) **source.com to x.x.x.x** following way:

Win OS:

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
x.x.x.x source.com
```

Linux OS:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/hosts
x.x.x.x source.com
```

Is it possible to do this at the level of Apache or PHP configuration (i.e., without interference in hosts file)?

Comment: I'm not clear what you want here. Where is the request being made from, and where do you need it to go to?

Comment: Request comes with a PHP-script on the domain1.com you need to go to a domain2.com (without interfering with the PHP-script itself)

Comment: Sorry, that isn't any clearer. Perhaps you could edit the question to include an example of the actual code you're trying to write? Remember that we know nothing about your code except what you tell us, however obvious it is to you after staring at the problem for hours.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to force the DNS resolution of `domain1.com` to another IP (say, `domain2.com`'s IP) but do not want to do this using `/etc/hosts` and would like to do it in the Apache or PHP configuration only.

Well here the problem is that PHP uses your server's DNS settings set in `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts` as an override, and Apache is just a web-server so it cannot change your application's logic or control it's networking.

What would be cleaner here is to save the IP of `domain2.com` in a php config file and call that IP with curl instead of `domain1.com`, and you can still add a `Host: domain1.com` header to your HTTP call if needed.

Edit : Here is an example using curl in PHP.

Let's say

- `domain1.com`'s IP is `1.1.1.1`
- `domain2.com`'s IP is `2.2.2.2`

If your goal is to call `2.2.2.2` but with the domain `domain1.com`, you just need to change the `Host` header of your HTTP request, like this :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://2.2.2.2/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: domain1.com'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly!

Explain an example please: "What would be cleaner here is to save the IP of domain2.com in a php config file and call that IP with curl instead of domain1.com, and you can still add a Host: domain1.com header to your HTTP call if needed."

Comment: I just added a PHP example.